# Why does ConEmu change the background color when I ssh?

Tags: conemu

I am using Vagrant to ssh to a Linux VM from windows in a ConEmu console.  Why I do that, the background color changes.  Is there some escape sequence that is doing this?  It doesn't happen when I ssh to other VMs.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by escape sequences around the "O" and "S" in /etc/motd.  Changing that file to contain just the characters "CoreOS (alpha)" fixed it.